# Import my input form values into a modal bootstrap

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am writing this topic to ask you a question and try to have a solution to this problem.

I am trying to make a system that sends messages to users registered on the website.
So I made a form with the infos I wanted and when you click on the send button, we display the "preview" of the message before sending it to the users.

The problem is that when I display the preview, the modal is displayed but not the values I have entered.

What is the solution to display the values and after clicking on the button sent in the form, send this beautiful message;)

Thanks for your reply: D
And yes, thanks google translate for this message.

(THE WEBSITE IS FRNECH)
(BOOTSTRAP 3.3.7 + PHP 7.0 AND last version of jQuery)

CODE PHP:

```html
<?php
//require 'form/haut.php'; //top of the page
?>


  <h1 class="page-header">Communiqué :</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <form method="POST" action="">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="objet_form">Objet de votre communiqué :</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="objet_form" name="objet_message_communique" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="message_form">Votre message :</label>
          <textarea rows="4" class="form-control" id="message_form" name="message_comminique"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="option_form" style="text-decoration: underline;">Option :</label><br/>
          <div id="option_form" style="padding-left: 10px;">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="option_send_message">Envoyer ce message par :</label>
              <div id="option_send_message">
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio_send_message_by" value="Email">Email</label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio_send_message_by" value="Messagerie_Site">Messagerie du site</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="option_send_message_rank">Envoyer ce message à :</label>
              <div id="option_send_message">
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio_send_message_for" value="Tous">Tous</label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio_send_message_for" value="Staff">Staff</label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio_send_message_for" value="Modérateurs">Modérateurs</label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio_send_message_for" value="Administrateurs">Administrateurs</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group"><label><label><input type="checkbox" value="" disabled> Avoir un rapport après envoi de ce communiqué</label></label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <a style="cursor: pointer;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#beforeSend"><button class="btn btn-primary">Envoyer ce communiqué</button></a>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  </div>


  <!-- Validation avant envoi communiqué -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="beforeSend" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">Confirmation avant envoi</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p>Voici à quoi votre communiqué va ressembler lors de la réception :</p>
          <!-- message qui sera envoyé -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="panel-body" style="border: 2px solid grey;border-radius: 2px;">
              <img style="" src="http://i.imgur.com/4AVxhnm.png" />
              <hr>
              <h4 style="text-align: center">Communiqué du $date</h4>
              <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><b>Objet :</b>
                <?= $_POST['objet_message_communique']; ?>
              </div>
              <div>
                <?= $message_comminique; ?><br/></div><br/><br/> Cordialement,
              <br/>
              <?= $userinfo['pseudo'].' , '.$userinfo['type_account'].' games.galilol.xyz'; ?><br/>
                <hr>
                <c style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><a href="http://games.galilol.xyz/" style="text-decoration: none;color: #000;">games.galilol.xyz</a> © 2017</c>
            </div>
          </div>
          <p>Voulez-vous confirmer l'envoi de ce message aux destinataires suivants : <b><?= $_POST['optradio_send_message_for'].' par '.$_POST['optradio_send_message_by']; ?></b></p>
          <a href="send"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> Envoyer ce communiqué</button></a>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Ne pas envoyer ce communiqué</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <?php 
  
  //require 'form/bas.php'; //bottom of the page
  
  ?>
```

TOP PAGE :

```html
<?php
require '../db.php';
session_start();
if ( $_SESSION['logged_in'] != 1 ) {

    $_SESSION['error_code'] = "21";
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Vous devez être connecté pour accéder à cette page !";
    $_SESSION['footer_message'] = "user_logged_in = 0";
    header("location: ../error.php");    
} else {
    $getid = intval($_SESSION['id']);
    $requsers = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM membres WHERE id = ?');
    $requsers->execute(array($getid));
    $userinfo = $requsers->fetch();
}

if (($userinfo['type_account'] == 'admin') OR ($userinfo['type_account'] == 'modo')) { 
} else {
    $_SESSION['error_code'] = "52";
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Vous n'avez pas les autorisations nécessaires pour entrer dans cette partie du site !";
    $_SESSION['footer_message'] = "--ERR_GROUP != list";
    header("location: ../error.php");  
}


//notification and stat
$n_report = '1';
$stats_report_db = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM report WHERE new_report = ?');
$stats_report_db->execute(array($n_report));
$stats_report_number = $stats_report_db->rowCount();





?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>cPanel | Galilol Games</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
    <link href="css/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Timeline CSS -->
    <link href="css/timeline.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/startmin.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Morris Charts CSS -->
    <link href="css/morris.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="../index.php">Galilol Games</a>
        </div>

        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">.</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

        <!-- Top Navigation: Left Menu -->
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left navbar-top-links">
            <li><a href="../index.php"><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i> Retourner sur le site web</a></li>
        </ul>

        <!-- Top Navigation: Right Menu -->
        <ul class="nav navbar-right navbar-top-links">
            <li class="dropdown navbar-inverse">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-bell fa-fw"></i> <b class="caret"></b>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-alerts">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div>
                                <i class="fa fa-comment fa-fw"></i> Nouveau évènements
                                <span class="pull-right text-muted small">timer-event-last</span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="text-center" href="#">
                            <strong>Voir tout les derniers évènements</strong>
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i><?php echo $userinfo['first_name']." ".$userinfo['last_name']; ?> <b class="caret"></b>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
                    <?php echo '<li><a href="../profil.php?id='.$userinfo['id'].'"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>Mon profil</a>'; ?>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a style="cursor: pointer;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#aboutInfo"><i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-fw"></i> A propos</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a style="cursor: pointer;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#disconnectInfo" ><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Se déconnecter</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
            <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">

                <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.php"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Tableau de bord</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sitemap fa-fw"></i> Communauté<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                            <li>
                                <a href="userlist.php"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> Liste des utilisateurs</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="search.php?general_search=user"><i class="fa fa-search fa-fw"></i> Rechercher un utilisateur</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bullhorn fa-fw"></i> Effectuer un communiqué</a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gamepad fa-fw"></i> Jeux<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-list" aria-hidden="true"></i> Liste des jeux</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i> Statistiques des jeux</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-database" aria-hidden="true"></i> Changer les valeurs d'un jeu</a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gavel fa-fw"></i> Sanctions <?php if($stats_report_number > 0){ echo '<span class="label label-danger">'.$stats_report_number.'</span>'; } ?><span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                            <li>
                                <a href="report.php"><i class="fa fa-flag fa-fw"></i> Liste des signalements <?php if($stats_report_number > 0){ echo '<span class="label label-danger">'.$stats_report_number.'</span>'; } ?></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="search.php?general_search=signalement"><i class="fa fa-search fa-fw"></i> Rechercher un signalement</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ban fa-fw"></i> Liste des bannisements</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                                <a href="emessagerie.php"><i class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> eMessagerie - Staff</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-life-ring fa-fw"></i> Support</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>

        </div>

    </nav>
    <!-- about modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="aboutInfo" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">A propos</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <h3 style="text-decoration: underline;">Information générale :</h3>
            <p>cPanel est un panel complet d'administration et de gestion de base de donnée créer par Rémi CELLARD et propulsé par Galilol Games.<br/>Le cPanel permet d'acccomplir toutes les tâches administratives pour une gestion complète et simple d'un site internet ayant une base de donnée.</p><br/>
            <h3 style="text-decoration: underline;">Note importante !</h3>
            <p>Le système cPanel a été créer par Rémi CELLARD et le design boosté par Start Bootstrap. Touts les droits leurs sont exclusif à eux (sauf autorisation de leur part).<br/><b>Il est interdit de copier le système et de le transmettre à quelconque personne ou de se faire passer pour son créateur. Tout les droits sur le cPanel sont exclusif à Rémi CELLARD et Start Bootstrap</b></p><br/>
            <h3 style="text-decoration: underline;">Un soucis ? Une question ?</h3>
            <p>contact.remicellard@gmail.com</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- disconnect modal validation -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="disconnectInfo" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading">Information</div>
          <div class="panel-body"><p>Êtes-vous sur de vouloir vous déconnectez ?</p>
            <a href="../disconnect.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Oui, je veut me déconnecter <i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i></button></a>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Non, je veut rester sur la page</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="page-wrapper">

        <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Bottom page :

```html
        <hr>
        <footer>
       <p>© Galilol Games 2017 | cPanel by Rémi CELLARD ©</p>
      </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
   
</div>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> 

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="js/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

<!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
<script src="js/startmin.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

/!\ DO NOT TRY TO RUN THIS PAGE /!\

Comment: You would get clearer and quicker answers if you show only the code that is relevant to your probem

Answer (score 0):

You haven't showed us where array $userinfo comes from, but in general getting values directly from the $_POST array should work:

```
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="panel-body" style="border: 2px solid grey;border-radius: 2px;">
          <img style="" src="http://i.imgur.com/4AVxhnm.png" />
          <hr>
          <h4 style="text-align: center">Communiqué du $date</h4>
          <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><b>Objet :</b>
            <?= $_POST['objet_message_communique']; ?>
          </div>
          <div>
            <?= $_POST['message_comminique']; ?><br/></div><br/><br/> Cordialement,
          <br/>
          <?= $_POST['pseudo'].' , '.$_POST['type_account'].' games.galilol.xyz'; ?><br/>
            <hr>
        </div>
```

Although you should validate user provided data before doing anything with them if you don't want to have security issuses.

Comment: Thank you for this information but it does not advance in the principle that my values that I entered in my form does not affect the modal. : |

Comment: If you want but I do not think that this will bring you to much in my problem ... look at the topic to have the whole php code

Comment: Maybe there is some error with the SQL connection or queries which causes problems that affect the modal. I don't know how could they but it wouldn't hurt if for the debugging you'd remove the whole PHP stuff from the top (include db.php, session etc.) and see if that changes anything - the values in the $_POST array should be available to you without any problems. Second thing - provide full action address `<form method="POST" action="">` because there could be some page redirections on the way (maybe .htaccess) which would cause the loss of the $_POST array on the way.